# How to select lossless image compression when exporting layer to image using QgsLayoutExporter

Tags: qgis, python, raster

I am working with QGIS 3.24 Tisler and Windows 10. I want to export raster and vector layers into PNG images. Here how I did

```
        exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)            
        settings = QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings()
        exporter.exportToImage(img_path, settings)
```

but I am getting PNG images with lossy compression. Can I set somewhere lossless compression? Where do I need to make changes to get lossless images?

Comment: What do you mean by lossy compression? PNG doesn't support that

Comment: I am not image format expert but I thought png always uses lossless compression. When exporting layouts via the GUI there is no option for compression settings with png. I guess the setting you are looking for would be: `settings.flags = QgsLayoutRenderContext.FlagLosslessImageRendering` but I tested with a .png image export and as expected it made no difference to the output image. You can also increase the dpi with `settings.dpi = 450` etc. About the flags, see: https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutRenderContext.html#aae823feceb47451b481ce3be51e37456

Comment: PNG *does* only use lossless compression.

Comment: Correction: use `layout.renderContext().setFlags(QgsLayoutRenderContext.FlagLosslessImageRendering)` to set render context flags. You can check with: `layout.renderContext().testFlag(QgsLayoutRenderContext.FlagLosslessImageRendering)` to see if it returns `True` or `False`. But I still don't think it will make any difference with png exports.

Comment: @BenW layout.renderContext().testFlag(QgsLayoutRenderContext.FlagLosslessImageRendering) returns True but doesn't create any difference

Comment: @user211640, yes I think that is expected. The test returning True, just means that the flag is set in the render context. As others have said, png is always a lossless format, so it's not surprising that it makes no difference. Direct quote from docs for `QgsLayoutRenderContext.FlagLosslessImageRendering`: "Render images losslessly whenever possible, instead of the default lossy jpeg rendering used for some destination devices (e.g. PDF)". Note: "whenever possible". What really is the problem? Is the exported layout image quality not to your liking? What is wrong with it?